# Multiple Variable in one SQL Like

Tags: php, mysql

I searched a lot and cannot find my answer. I'm trying to include 2 variable in my like statement to match a date that wasn't formatted correctly in a database I'm working on.

I need to:

```
Select count(*) as ABC 
    from database 
    where active like '1' 
        and agent = '$Employeestringid' 
        AND time LIKE '%$FilterMonth_%_$queryyear'"
```

The part that is currently not working is: `'%$FilterMonth_%_$queryyear'`

I need it to work and match a date formatted like:  `'9:10:31 PM Fri, May 20th 2016'` by only capturing MONTH and YEAR.

Comment: Why not just part out the time to the two values being passed in and do an equality check? Consider `and year(time) = $Queryyear and month(time) = $FilterMonth`  [Doc Date Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When interpolating your variables in the string, PHP reads the `_` as part of the variable name.

You need to use `{}` to prevent this behavior:

```
$query = "Select count(*) as ABC 
    from database 
    where active like '1' 
        and agent = '$Employeestringid' 
        AND time LIKE '%{$FilterMonth}_%_{$queryyear}'";
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked - thank you very much for your quick help Rocket :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the underscores

```
'%$FilterMonth%$queryyear'
```

Comment: Thanks Mojtaba - The recommendation that I received from Rocket worked in my code :) Problem solved.

Comment: @SiREKT. Glad to hear that. So, please mark it as solved